# How to make QPushButtons to add text into QLineEdit box?

Tags: qt, virtual-keyboard

I used Qt Creator to make a "keyboard" window with sixty QPushButtons and one QLineEdit. How can I make the buttons to add characters into QLineEdit text box? If I press a QPushButton with the label 'Q' on it, I want the program to add the Unicode character 'Q' on the text box.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys, but Qt Creator seems to be so messy that I have no clue what to do with it.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this would be to just connect the 'clicked' signal from all the buttons to a slot, and then handle the adding of the character there.

For example, if the all keyboard buttons are inside a layout called 'buttonLayout', in your MainWindow constructor you can do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ui->buttonLayout->count(); ++i)
{
    QWidget* widget = ui->buttonLayout->itemAt( i )->widget();
    QPushButton* button = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>( widget );

    if ( button )
    {
        connect( button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(keyboardButtonPressed()) );
    }
}
```

Then in the slot implementation, you can use QObject::sender(), which returns the object that sent the signal:

```
void MainWindow::keyboardButtonPressed()
{
    QPushButton* button = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>( sender() );

    if ( button )
    {
        ui->lineEdit->insert( button->text() );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**OPTION 1 - Multiple signals and slots**

Connect all pushbuttons `clicked()` signal to a slot

```
// Let button01 be the A 
connect(ui->button01, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(buttonClicked()));
...
// Let button 60 be the Q
connect(ui->button60, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(buttonClicked()));
```

In the `buttonClicked()` slot you have to figure out which button was clicked and append the corresponding letter to the line edit.

```
void buttonClicked()
{
    QObject* callingButton = QObject::sender();
    if (callingButton == button01)
        ui->lineEdit->setText(ui->lineEdit->text()+ "A");
    ...
    else if (callingButton == button60)
        ui->lineEdit->setText(ui->lineEdit->text()+ "Q");
}
```

**OPTION 2 - Subclass QPushButton**

You could subclass `QPushButton` in order to avoid the multiple ifs. In your subclass just catch the mouse release event and emit a new signal which will contain the button's text

```
void KeyboardButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
   emit clicked(buttonLetter); // Where button letter a variable of every item of your subclass
}
```

Similarly connect the clicked(QString) signal with a slot

```
connect(ui->button01, SIGNAL(clicked(QString)), this, SLOT(buttonClicked(QString)));
...
connect(ui->button60, SIGNAL(clicked(QString)), this, SLOT(buttonClicked(QString)));

void buttonClicked(QString t)
{
    ui->lineEdit->setText(ui->lineEdit->text()+ t);
}
```

Comment: Both subclassing and if else cascades can be avoided by either qobject_cast'ing sender() to QPushButton and using text(), or by setting a dynamic property (QObject::setProperty) on each button holding the text to paste. The latter gives some more flexibility if the text of the button and the letter to add are different (like for enter etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I have created an application with a similar issue, trying to convert the qpushbutton text to the qlineedit itself. The key is how you initialize the buttons and to use polymorphism in your function. To create an emit signal wont work for individual characters. The .digitValue will work if the case if for numerics (which the buttons would be of type int), but qt doesnt have a character value (I should say after 6hrs of reading qt doc and another 4 of trying different combinations it would not work), I think it has to do with how many bits it takes to store each variable type in an array. I even tried converting the button->text to QString to use with the emit function as a signal prototyped.

I do not know what your button layout is, but I will give you a synopsis of what I did. I first created a global, static const char array containing all the letters needed e.g.

```
static const char vowelarray[] = "AEIOU";
```

Then initialized the QPushButtons with in the MainWindow function, using iteration, setting a for loop's terminating condition equal to the size char array (in your case 60?). This all depends on your button layout though. I personally created a void function (setLocation) for the button->setGeometry of each button and iterated the setGeometry, and then passed the function to the MainWindow Function, at end of fucntion. The following code was used to initialize the buttons, connect signals to slots, and use polymorphism to connect to lineedit.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
    characterButton[i] = new QPushButton(chararry[i], this);    `
    characterButton[i] -> setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background: grey; color: brown}");
    connect(characterButton[i],SIGNAL(released(),this,SLOT(characterPushed()));
}

setLocation();
```

Then created a void function (e.g. void MainWindow::characterPuched()) where the following code was used:

```
void MainWindow::characterPushed(){
    QPushButton *characterButton = (QPushButton*) sender();
    if (characterButton )
    {
        lineEdit -> setText(letters.insert(letters.size(), characterButton -> text()));
    }
    lineEdit -> setText(letters);

}
```

of course letters was a global variable as well as:

```
QString letters = "";
```

and of course the QPushButtons and the function were prototype in the header file as a private variables and slots, e.g.

```
private:
    QPushButton *characterButton[26];
```

the variable 'letters' was used to extract and input text to and from the line edit for further functions throughout the application.
Best Luck!!``